# How to set a width constraint on a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit, autolayout

I have a button that I want to be a constant size across all devices (iPhone 4,5,6, iPad...etc). I want that button to be 347 x 66 pixels wide. I currently have the following constraints:

[image: constraints]

However, the width constraint isn't followed. This is what it looks like when ran in simulation:

[image: constraints problem]

Any ideas on how to get it to always be 374 pixels wide on any device ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always design in points not pixels, which is why constraints are in points. The iPhones up to the 5s are all 320 points across in portrait mode, so 374 points would be wider than the screen. The two iPhone 6 models are a bit wider, in points.  The simulator image you posted is indeed trying to show a button which is 374 points wide, i.e. wider than the screen. Perhaps you intended to make a button which is half that width, 187 points, which is 374 pixels on a 2x retina screen?

Comment: Lesson learnt the hard way. Points != Pixels. Thanks. Ended up having to change the Points Width constraint to 259 to get it to equal 374 pixels